# Reading text from file to unsigned char array, errors while trying to use example

Tags: c++, arrays, file, unsigned-char

I'm trying to use example from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832677/1816083
but i have:

```
invalid conversion from `unsigned char*' to `char*'
initializing argument 1 of `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' 
invalid conversion from `void*' to `size_t'
```

in line:

```
size_t bytes_read = myfile.read((unsigned char *) buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: That could be part of the reason the answer you link to didn't get a single vote. ;)

Comment: @NPE There's one now. Well, -1 that is.

Comment: Do you just want the whole file into a linear array with one big fat read? or are you processing this one buffer-size at a time?

Comment: I suggest to flag inappropriate answer, that leads to this question(http://stackoverflow.com/a/6832677/1816083), for removal, it confuses people

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `read()` takes a `char*` rather than `unsigned char*`. Secondly, it does not return the number of characters read.

Instead, try:

```
myfile.read((char*)buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
std::streamsize bytes_read = myfile.gcount();
```

Comment: invalid conversion from `unsigned char*' to `char*' maybe some include missing? i'm noob in cpp

Comment: @cerber remove word `unsigned` from buffer's definition

Comment: @kassak he needs it as an `unsigned char` array (see the title of the question). He should *add* a `(char *)` cast to the first param of the `.read()` call.

Comment: @WhozCraig yep, missed this, looking only at question's body

Comment: #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

//...

ifstream myfile("myfile.bin", ios::binary);
if (myfile)
{
  size_t bytes_read = myfile.read(( char *) buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
}
        return 0;
}
invalid conversion from `void*' to `size_t'

Comment: @cerber that would be because the read operation does not return the size read. It returns a reference to the stream object. Use the `myfile.gcount()` as NPE's answer here shows to get the last-read size.

Comment: myfile.read((char *)buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
std::streamsize bytes_read = myfile.gcount();  , compiles should be ok, thanks

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the compiler's output is quite enought. It tells you, that you're trying to give `unsigned char*` to function, that waits `char*`. BTW, there is even a function name

```
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize)
[with _CharT = char ...
```

If you need `unsigned chars buffer[ ... ]` then cast it to `char*`

```
unsigned char buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
ifstream myfile("myfile.bin", ios::binary);
if (myfile)
{
    myfile.read((char*) buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    //          ^^^^^^^
    size_t bytes_read = myfile.gcount();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6832677/1816083 , so this example is bad, how to do this properly?

Comment: @cerber And what do you always believe people?)

Comment: "so this example is bad" - yes. "how to do this properly?" - declare `buffer` as array of `char`'s or cast it to `char*` instead of `unsigned char*`

Comment: but i need uchar array

Comment: Then cast it to `char*`. BTW, you choose that answer with negative vote, while there was another answers =)